# ImportError: No module named 'prep_terrain_data'

Tags: python, import

I am trying to execute from prep_terrain_data import makeTerrainData. I get
"ImportError: No module named 'prep_terrain_data'"

- I tried adding "Anaconda_New\Lib\site-packages" path to sys.path as it contains six.
- created **init**.py in all the directories.

But didnt solve the problem. I am using anaconda 3 2.4.0

Comment: it is `__init__.py` rather than just `init.py`. Also the information you provided is not enough. Give detail description about the OS and python version you're running also the absolute location of your module.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I used __init__.py. OS is windows 7, 64 bit and python version is from Anaconda python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

In the same directory, you should create a file called "prep_terrain_data.py"

Then put this in there:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random


def makeTerrainData(n_points=1000):
###############################################################################
### make the toy dataset
    random.seed(42)
    grade = [random.random() for ii in range(0,n_points)]
    bumpy = [random.random() for ii in range(0,n_points)]
    error = [random.random() for ii in range(0,n_points)]
    y = [round(grade[ii]*bumpy[ii]+0.3+0.1*error[ii]) for ii in range(0,n_points)]
    for ii in range(0, len(y)):
        if grade[ii]>0.8 or bumpy[ii]>0.8:
            y[ii] = 1.0

### split into train/test sets
    X = [[gg, ss] for gg, ss in zip(grade, bumpy)]
    split = int(0.75*n_points)
    X_train = X[0:split]
    X_test  = X[split:]
    y_train = y[0:split]
    y_test  = y[split:]

    grade_sig = [X_train[ii][0] for ii in range(0, len(X_train)) if y_train[ii]==0]
    bumpy_sig = [X_train[ii][1] for ii in range(0, len(X_train)) if y_train[ii]==0]
    grade_bkg = [X_train[ii][0] for ii in range(0, len(X_train)) if y_train[ii]==1]
    bumpy_bkg = [X_train[ii][1] for ii in range(0, len(X_train)) if y_train[ii]==1]

#    training_data = {"fast":{"grade":grade_sig, "bumpiness":bumpy_sig}
#            , "slow":{"grade":grade_bkg, "bumpiness":bumpy_bkg}}


    grade_sig = [X_test[ii][0] for ii in range(0, len(X_test)) if y_test[ii]==0]
    bumpy_sig = [X_test[ii][1] for ii in range(0, len(X_test)) if y_test[ii]==0]
    grade_bkg = [X_test[ii][0] for ii in range(0, len(X_test)) if y_test[ii]==1]
    bumpy_bkg = [X_test[ii][1] for ii in range(0, len(X_test)) if y_test[ii]==1]

    test_data = {"fast":{"grade":grade_sig, "bumpiness":bumpy_sig}
            , "slow":{"grade":grade_bkg, "bumpiness":bumpy_bkg}}

    return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test
#    return training_data, test_data
```

This should solve the problem, you can now import from prep_terrain_data.